# Quick-Select worst-case scenario (Θ(n^2) or O(n^2)?)

Tags: time-complexity, quickselect

I have been trying to understand the Quick-Select algorithm and I have found two different values for the complexity of the worst-case running time.

For example, [This website](https://eugene-eeo.github.io/blog/randomized-quickselect.html) claims that worst-case time complexity is Θ(n^2), whilst [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quickselect-algorithm/) claims that it's O(n^2).

Can someone help me understand which one is correct and why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct, but using Θ is a stronger statement. Big O notation gives an asymptotic upper bound, whereas big Theta notation gives the actual asymptotic growth rate.

As an analogy, imagine Alice and Bob are both counting somebody's legs. Alice says `legs = 2`, and Bob says `legs ≤ 2`. Alice and Bob are both correct, but Alice's statement is stronger.

In informal use, it's quite common to write O when you could have written the stronger statement with Θ, just because most people's keyboards don't have a Θ key.